# Breakpoints get unbound on debug session start

Tags: wordpress, visual-studio-code

When I start a debug session with a set breakpoint in a js file the breakpoint gets unbound as soon as the debug session starts. Disabling and enabling the same breakpoint turns it red again and it then breaks correctly. When I restart the session the issue starts again. Putting the debugger statement inside the js file breaks at the line everytime correctly.

This seems to be related to a local webserver set up and might be a path mapping issue. So here is the configuration:

- Windows 10
- xampp webserver
- wordpress installed to c:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress

launch.json

```
{
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "type": "pwa-msedge",
        "request": "launch",
        "name": "Launch Edge against localhost",
        "url": "http://localhost/wordpress",
        "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
        "trace": true
    } 
]
```

}

Screenshot of debug breakpoint diagnostics after start when readding the breakpoint (Correct)
[image]

Screenshot of debug breakpoint diagnostics after start with previously set breakpoint (Wrong)
[image]

I tested everything with a minimal setup of a fresh folder with only a index.html and a script.js file without a problem. So there is a mapping issue, but also after 2 days of googling I couldn't find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question:

I ended up setting up a virtual host for my wordpresssite which makes it possible to access the homepage via inlivitytestsite.com. Then this launch.json finally worked:

```
  "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "pwa-msedge",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Edge against localhost",
            "url": "http://inlivitytestsite.com",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "pathMapping": {
                "/wp-content/plugins/inlivity_product_configurator": "C:\\LocalProjects\\WP-Plugin-Dev\\inlivity_product_configurator"
            }
        }
    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

I randomly had got this `unbound breakpoint` issue. Only workaround I am using right now is to press `Ctrl+Shift+P` and then select "Debug: Start Debugging and Stop on Entry"[image]

I was able to get rid `unbound breakpoints` issue now.